# CakePHP and Facebook PHP SDK: Proper way of handling tasks?

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, task

I am trying to work on a web app that makes use of the Facebook PHP SDK with CakePHP as my framework.

Initially, I was pulling a bunch of facebook data in my controllers, but noticed that the Facebook API calls take a lot of time.  So I thought about using cakePHP Shell Tasks in order to pull down the facebook data via scheduled cron jobs.

First a general question: is this the correct way to handle a situation like this?  As in, using shell tasks to be used in cron jobs.

Secondly, currently my logic to connect to FB, pull down data, save into the db are all in controller actions.  How can I access these actions from the shell Task?

Lastly, Facebook requires the user to be logged in to pull the data.  If I use cron jobs, how will the user be logged in?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways in which you can address this issue.

The easiest would probably be an asynchronous AJAX request to get the data while the user is browsing your site (this requires of course that the user can browse your site without actually "leaving" the page).

If you'd go for delayed tasks with cron, (or beanstalkd, or delayed job, try Googleing them) you probably need some more privileges in your facebook integration, specifically the "offline access" feature. ["This permission makes the access token returned by our OAuth endpoint long-lived."](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) You will then be able to make OAuth calls from a cake shell to retrieve the data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you!  I had set up a cake shell and tasks and tried to get itto play nicely with the restof my code and the facebook.php SDK, but not quite yet there.  I need to work on that today!  That being said, I've been trying to follow cakephp's MVC philosophy.  I don't really understand where cake shell/tasks fall into the philosophy.  Should I have the cake shell call one of the Controllers which has code for pulling down data from FB?  Or should the shell code itself pull down the FB data directly?

Comment: You should not call controllers from the shell, no. Try to do as much as possible with your models. You can even try one of the Restful/Oauth/Facebook datasources for CakePHP to work with a Facebook Model if you want. Try Google, there are a lot of datasources available in the community. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use a distributed job server like GearMan or ZeroMQ which works very very well with PHP. And then after collecting the access tokens with offline_permission, register those tasks as a "job" in GearMan or ZeroMQ and process them with the worker scripts. Its easy to start with GearMan.

1. http://www.masnun.me/2011/09/30/gear-up-your-php-apps-with-gearman.html
2. http://www.masnun.me/2011/09/30/installing-and-getting-started-with-gearman.html

Hope it will help.

Comment: THank you!  I had never heard of gearman.  I've just read through IBM's page on this, but I'm unclear how to integrate it with cakephp yet.  Does the framework I'm using make a difference whether I can use gearman?